# Angular How to display a pie chart with dynamic data?

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, ng2-charts, angular-chart

i have multiple functions that return numbers (statistics) i want to use those numbers and display them in a pie chart in angular.

i have tried to use ng2-chart and then pass in my function in place of the number like this

```
  public pieChartData: number[] = [this.function1(), this.function2(), this.function3()];
```

but nothing was displayed, it looked like data wasnt bind.

here is an example of a function

```
function1() {
    const myList = this.entries.filter(entry => entry.status === 'some string');
    return myList.length;
}
```

so my question is how to render a chart using dynamic data in angular?

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#/LineChart

Comment: Samples are provided with data.